# How to update tableview cells instead of reloading?

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata, pull-to-refresh

I am building iOS Application using storyboards.

I have a tableview for displaying multiple datas from database.

Also i am using pull down refresh.

In PullDownRefresh i called a method [(void)updateData] where i reload tableview.

At that time image in the cell blinks abruptly while scrolling.

So instead of reloading tableView, i want to update the tableView.

That means i want to add new rows from the last cell.

I am beginnner in iOS.Help is Appreciated.

Comment: You may not have a option other than to reload the table, however, i see SDWebImage framework might help you in this regards. SDWebImage will add your image to the cache and displays it at a faster refresh rate than the normal images. Though it requires a bit of work to be done.

Comment: Do you ever use the frameWork

Comment: yes, i have used this particular framework in my image rich gaming application and it worked beautifully.

Comment: can u please sent the code.

Comment: Please refer [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Answer (score 1):

You may use insertRowsAtIndexPaths of UITableView-

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableDatalist insertObject:obj atIndex:index];

        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    });
```

Comment: what the 3rd line denotes.I don't understand self.tableDataList

Comment: Its a array of data which Uitableview reload at cellatindexofrow

Comment: At the time of upDate what will be the obj and index.Sorry i am a beginner 1st time i am updating tableview.